# Array has append, but no value inside

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, rest

I've declared a String array in my Swift file.

```
var postTitleArray : [String] = []
```

In my `viewDidLoad` method, I've append values into my array...

```
RestApiManager.sharedInstance.makeGetRequest("/development/vw_posts?filter=parent_term_id%20%3D%20%22%5B82%5D%22", onCompletion: { json in
    for result in json["record"].arrayValue
    {
       let postTitle = result["post_title"].stringValue
       print(postTitle)
       self.postTitleArray.append(postTitle)
    }
})
```

Other than that, I've use the count of array into the numberOfRowsInSection to set the rows number of my tableView...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.postTitleArray.count
}
```

However, the numberOfRowsInSection has return 0, why could it happened, I've assigned value into my **postTitleArray**, anyone can help me take a look on this? Appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API call is likely not finished before `numberOfRowsInSection` is called.

Try calling `reloadData` on your `UITableView` instance after you have populated your `postTitleArray`.  (I'm assuming here you have a reference to your `UITableView` and it's called `tableView`)

```
RestApiManager.sharedInstance.makeGetRequest("/development/vw_posts?filter=parent_term_id%20%3D%20%22%5B82%5D%22", onCompletion: { json in
    for result in json["record"].arrayValue
    {
       let postTitle = result["post_title"].stringValue
       print(postTitle)
       self.postTitleArray.append(postTitle)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: I did it dude, millions thanks for your answer! Do you mind to explain to me why we should reload table data after we append into the Array?

Comment: No problem. Updating a `UITableView` data source doesn't automatically reload the table.  You as the developer need to decide when it's appropriate to refresh the table.  For example, calling `reloadData` after a single title has been appended would likely be very slow if you were adding 1000 titles to the array.

Comment: Okay, I got what you said in this case, if we really got 1000 records in the Array, we should limit the number of getting it at the beginning right?

Comment: More generally, there are many reasons you might not want to update the user interface when your data source changes.  You have the power to call `reloadData` to update your user interface when it's appropriate.

Comment: Got it now, thanks for your information. Thousand of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check :

```
if let postTitle = result["post_title"]?.stringValue{
       self.postTitleArray.append(postTitle)
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```